# Is a byte array allocated with new[] aligned on platform word boundary?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, new-operator, memory-alignment

Consider the following code on 64-bit platform:

```
uint8_t* ptr = new uint8_t[16];
ptr[0] = 1;
*reinterpret_cast<double*>(ptr+8) = 1.0;
```

If the initially allocated byte array is not aligned on 8-byte boundary, then the assignment of `double` value will require the processor to write 2 64-bit memory cells. Can this happen? Does the standard guarantee any alignment of byte array allocated with new[]?
I suppose `new double[2]` must allocate something aligned on 8-byte boundary. Is this true?

Comment: Until someone can quote actual wording from the standard - the C++ standard guarantees alignment for IIRC all standard-C++ primitive types, so if the biggest-alignment C++ type is `double`, your `new` will give you memory suitably aligned for double. However, some platform-specific types (notably types for use with SIMD intrinsics, probably some stuff related to graphics cards) aren't included in that. For things like that, check your compilers documentation. BTW - on some platforms it's not just performance, unaligned access may not be supported at all.